# How to select single item (not row) from a tkinter treeview and grid

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, treeview

I have this code (which I unabashedly stole from here:https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-treeview/):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Treeview demo')
root.geometry('620x200')

# define columns
columns = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings')

# define headings
tree.heading('first_name', text='First Name')
tree.heading('last_name', text='Last Name')
tree.heading('email', text='Email')

# generate sample data
contacts = []
for n in range(1, 100):
    contacts.append((f'first {n}', f'last {n}', f'email{n}@example.com'))

# add data to the treeview
for contact in contacts:
    tree.insert('', tk.END, values=contact)


def item_selected(event):
    for selected_item in tree.selection():
        item = tree.item(selected_item)
        record = item['values']
        # show a message
        showinfo(title='Information', message=','.join(record))


tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', item_selected)

tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

# add a scrollbar
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=tree.yview)
tree.configure(yscroll=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

# run the app
root.mainloop()
```

The problem I am having is that clicking on the grid/tree always selects and returns the entire row.  I need to know what cell the user clicked on.

Comment: There is `.identify()` to find which row and column is clicked using the mouse position.

Answer (score 1):

The tree has a method named `identify` which can be used to identify an item and column by the x/y coordinate of the event. The treeview method `set` can be used to extract data based on the item id and the column id (if you don't pass a new value to `set`, it returns the current value).

Instead of binding to `<<TreeviewSelect>>` you can bind to a button click in order to get the information under the cursor using these methods.

For example, this will print the data of the item in the row and column under the mouse:

```
def item_selected(event):
    item_id = tree.identify("item", event.x, event.y)
    column_id = tree.identify("column", event.x, event.y)
    data = tree.set(item_id, column_id)
    showinfo(title="Information", message=f"you clicked on {data}")
```

You can bind to this function like so:

```
tree.bind("<1>", item_selected)
```

Note: The treeview widget will not allow you to select just a single cell. It only supports the selection of an entire row.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  item_id and column_id both are '' in the callback.  I think I need to go another route as I really need the user to be able to select a single cell

Comment: @jordanthompson I think you do what Bryan said inside the callback for `<<TreeviewSelect>>` event, not `<1>`.  If this is the case, then `event.x` and `event.y` (they are both 0) will not be the real position of the mouse cursor.

Comment: @jordanthompson:  This code works for me. It computes the correct data from the correct column. But yeah, if you need to select a single cell, the tree view isn’t the right widget.